# QSortFilterProxyModel: allow new item

Tags: python, pyqt, qcombobox

I'm trying to implement a QCombobox with autocompletion and filtering. I found examples with QSortFilterProxyModel, however it doesn't behave like I would: I can't add a new string to create a new item (if it is not in the list).

Do you have any tips? Should I implement a custom ProxyModel, or is it impossible to do so?

MWE (I would also like to add a default value "" when the window is shown):

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QComboBox, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedWidth(400)

        self.cB_opc_type = QComboBox(self)
        self.cB_opc_type.setEditable(True)
        self.cB_opc_type.setFixedHeight(60)
        self.cB_opc_type.setFixedWidth(300)

        self.lst = ["Abcd", "Abka", "Dezea", "Bddqdq", "Excqq"]
        self.lst.sort()
        self.qlst = QtCore.QStringListModel()
        self.qlst.setStringList(self.lst)

        self.ProxyModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.ProxyModel.setSourceModel(self.qlst)
        self.ProxyModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.ProxyModel.setDynamicSortFilter(True)
        self.ProxyModel.setSortRole(QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        self.cB_opc_type.setModel(self.ProxyModel)

        self.completer = QtWidgets.QCompleter(self.ProxyModel, self)
        self.completer.setCompletionMode(QtWidgets.QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
        self.cB_opc_type.setCompleter(self.completer)

        self.cB_opc_type.editTextChanged.connect(self.maj_items)

    def maj_items(self, etc):
        self.ProxyModel.setFilterFixedString(etc)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: You could better explain the following: *however it doesn't behave like I would: I can't add a new string to create a new item (if it is not in the list)*

Comment: Currently, when I begin typing, it suggests the existing items, but I can't write a custom string which is not in the model list. I would like to do so, to be able to select an item or to "create" a new one. Is it clearer?

Comment: mmm, I don't understand you, explain yourself in more detail from the user's point of view. Let's say that the user writes "hello" then before what action of the user (press any button or key for example) should this new text be added to the default suggestions

Comment: For example: the list contains "hi", "hey", "goodbye" and the user wants to write "hello". 
What I would like: when he types "h", only "hi" and "hey" are suggested (in a popup window below). Then when he types "e", only "hey". And after nothing is suggested and he writes "llo". Currently, with the proxy, he can't write "hello", the user is stuck to "hey" because "hello" is not in the list...

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about MWE! I added one. I hope it is clear and adequate.